# Is there a way to increase BLE advertisement frequency in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, android-ibeacon

I have an Android device broadcasting a BLE advertisement using the following commands of AltBeacon library:

```
ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY  approx 1 Hz
ADVERTISE_MODE_BALANCED     approx 3 Hz
ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_POWER    approx 10 Hz
```

I would like to increase this frequency more than 10 times per second. Is there a way to increase advertising frequency in Android? Or it is unchangeable?

Comment: 100ms is the highest frequency you can broadcast with. That is also usually the maximum common devices allow you to set.

Answer (score 2):

You can reach it with stopping and starting advertisement with code like this:

```
while (true) {
    beaconTransmitter.stopAdvertising()
    beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon, object : AdvertiseCallback() }
```

Answer (score 1):

The different options you have shown that work with the Android Beacon Library's BeaconTransmitter class are built-in to Android.  Unfortunately **there are no other higher frequencies of transmission offered by Android** APIs.

However, on many newer devices **you may start more than one advertiser at a time**.   If you have a device like this (Pixel, Nexus,  Galaxy, Nokia)  you can simply start more than one BeaconTransmitter instance at a time, each set to advertise 10Hz.  **If you start 10, you effectively get advertising at 100Hz.**